# Unable to Mount an NFS Share with AutoFS

Tags: linux, debian, nfs, autofs

I'm trying to mount an NFS share `/data`  hosted on `server_host` to a folder also called `/data` on `server_client`. I am able to mount it on startup with the fstab file and I am able to mount it on-demand with `sudo mount -t nfs server_host:/data /data`. So with NFS set up properly and only two config files to edit, it should be trivial to edit a couple AutoFS config files and get it working. But despite following every tutorial I find online to the word and it's not working.

Here is my `auto.master`

`/-    /etc/auto.master.d/data.dir`

Here is my `auto.master.d/data.dir`

`/data   -fstype=nfs,rw server_host:/data`

When I run `sudo automount -f -v -d` I get

````
using kernel protocol version 5.05
lookup_nss_read_master: reading master file /etc/auto.master
do_init: parse(sun): init gathered global options: (null)
lookup_read_master: lookup(file): read entry +dir:/etc/auto.master.d
lookup_nss_read_master: reading master dir /etc/auto.master.d
lookup_read_master: lookup(dir): scandir: /etc/auto.master.d
lookup_read_master: lookup(file): read entry +auto.master
lookup_nss_read_master: reading master files auto.master
do_init: parse(sun): init gathered global options: (null)
lookup_read_master: lookup(file): read entry /-
master_do_mount: mounting /-
automount_path_to_fifo: fifo name /var/run/autofs.fifo--
lookup_nss_read_map: reading map file /etc/auto.master.d/data.dir
do_init: parse(sun): init gathered global options: (null)
mounted direct on /data with timeout 300, freq 75 seconds
do_mount_autofs_direct: mounted trigger /data
st_ready: st_ready(): state = 0 path /-
handle_packet: type = 5
handle_packet_missing_direct: token 39, name /data, request pid 608
attempting to mount entry /data
lookup_mount: lookup(file): looking up /data
lookup_mount: lookup(file): /data -> -fstype=nfs,rw server_host:/data
parse_mount: parse(sun): expanded entry: -fstype=nfs,rw server_host:/data
parse_mount: parse(sun): gathered options: fstype=nfs,rw
parse_mount: parse(sun): dequote("server_host:/data") -> server_host:/data
parse_mount: parse(sun): core of entry: options=fstype=nfs,rw, loc=server_host:/data
sun_mount: parse(sun): mounting root /data, mountpoint /data, what server_host:/data, fstype nfs, options rw
mount(nfs): root=/data name=/data what=server_host:/data, fstype=nfs, options=rw
mount(nfs): nfs options="rw", nobind=0, nosymlink=0, ro=0
get_nfs_info: called with host server_host(server_host) proto 6 version 0x20
get_nfs_info: error 0x0 getting getting portmap client
get_nfs_info: called with host server_host(server_host) proto 17 version 0x20
get_nfs_info: host not reachable or timed out getting service port
mount(nfs): no hosts available
dev_ioctl_send_fail: token = 39
**failed to mount /data**```
````

Comment: You can see the `get_nfs_info: host not reachable or timed out getting service port` message. Try to check few things: 1. `tcpdump -s0 -v host server_host` and check the network communication, if it indeed tries to contact the host. 2. `strace -f -o <outfile> -p \`pgrep automount\``, and search in the file the server_host and it's IP address, it might give you some clue. You can edit your question and add any of the data there and we'll try to help.

Comment: Yes, I am able to communicate freely between the devices. NFS with the ```mount``` method or fstab file works, just not ```autofs```. I believe the issue is stemming from me using ZFS, perhaps ```autofs``` does not support that filesystem. I searched online however and couldn't find any information about it.

Comment: `autofs` doesn't care which file system it mounts on. It just uses a regular `mount` command behind the scenes just like you do. Also, notice that it fails because `host not reachable or timed out getting service port`, which means it didn't even try to mount the disk. `autofs` first attempts to check connectivity to the destination, and if it fails it doesn't even run the `mount` command. That's why I suggested to use `strace` and `tcpdump`. You will be able to see there the exact host and port it tries to connect. Once you have this data and post it here I'll probably be able to help you.

Comment: By the way, `-port=2049` to the mount options in your `auto.master.d/data.dir` file? So the line should look as follows: `/data   -port=2049,-fstype=nfs,rw server_host:/data`